# How can i get really host in URL of web browser in java web application, when use tomcat proxyhost

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, proxy, host

I am used to use `getServerName()` method of `HttpServletRequest` class for getting host string.

In my project, the server that I am servicing ran with proxy host environment. in this case `getServerName()` method return a address that will was redirected.

So I set hostname that use in my web application to `proxyName` property in the `server.xml` file.

Then the hostname that my use in project is one depth domain.

That will contains `www` at front or will not contains.

But `proxyName` is static string such as either `www.host.net` or `host.net`.

So depending on whether the really hostname in URL contains `www` or not, that is same as `proxyName` property or not same.

In this case, how can i get really host in URL of web browser in Java web application, when use **Tomcat** proxyhost.

Comment: Does your Proxy write(or rewrite) HTTP request header fields such as 'Host' like: 
 https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/#passing-request-headers?
If so, you can get the hostname seen by a web browser by using `HttpServletRequest#getHeader`.

Comment: Thanks to your comment Tomoki. I will test your suggest in my product server at next week.